# Standard topology definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (real number system) is the topology $T$ whose open sets consist of unions of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open if, for each $x \in U$, there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)$. Note that $\emptyset \in T$ trivially.

Could you explain what standard topology is. I can understand the last sentences but I have a problem with the first sentence. What does "open sets consist of unions of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$"? Could you write what the topology is equal to? Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you understand what an open interval is in $\Bbb R$? And do you know what union means?

Comment: @Clayton Yes, I do

Comment: Try to build up your intuition on that doing examples: is $(1,2)$ open according to the definition? Or in other words, can you find an interval $(a,b)$ for any point $x$ in $(1,2)$ such that $x \in (a,b) \subset (1,2)$? What about $\{0\}, [1,2), (1,2) \cup (3,4)$?

Comment: 'What does "open sets consist of unions of open intervals in R" mean?'  It means exactly what it sounds like.  A set $S \subset \mathbb R$ is open if it is a union of open intervals.  It is not open if it is not a union of open intervals.  That is a definition.

Comment: @Gibbs Only (1,2) is an open interval on the real number line. But I cannot think of any standard topology. Could you, please, give an example of standard topology?

Comment: @fleablood thanks, I understand this definition now. But I'd like to see an example of this topology as I cannot think of any such topology.

Comment: A "topology" is a rule or list that says "We are arbitrarily call some subsets 'open';  The following list or rules will simply tell us which ones"  So this says "If $S$ is a union of open intervals we are going to say that $S$ is open;  that is what 'open' is going to mean to us."

Comment: @Learningmath I suggest you look again at the definition of standard topology. I cannot give an 'example' of standard topology. It is just the one you defined in your question.

Comment: So $(1,0) \cup (\frac 12, 3)$ is an open set.  But $\{7\}$ is not.  Also $(0, \infty) = \cup_{n\in \mathbb N} (n-1, n+ 2)$ is an open set.

Comment: I can not give you an "example" of the standard topology of $\mathbb R$.  There is one and one only and "the real numbers where the 'open' sets are unions of open intervals".  Maybe you need an example of a topology that *isn't* standard.  Here's one "all sets are open. period."  Here's another "Other than $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$, *no* sets are open.  Period."

Comment: The last sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The open sets consists of unions of SETS OF open intervals. That is, $S$ is open iff there exists a set $C$ of open intervals such that $S=\cup C=\{r: \exists c\in C\;(x\in C)\}. $

A 'union of open intervals" is a commonly-used abbreviation for this.